# Sufficient conditions for existence of Riemann–Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I wanted to know what are various sufficient conditions for existence of Riemann–Stieltjes integral. The most 'general' i know is when $F$ and $g$ are functions of bounded variation on $[a,b]$, $F$ and $g$ are continuous from the right (in $[a,b)$) and left (in $[a,b)$) respectively.
What are the other non-trivial conditions that you know of ?

Comment: If this is included in what you want, consider those sufficient conditions for the properties you mentioned as the sufficient condition for RS integral

Answer (score 1):

The existence of the Riemann–Stieltjes integral of a bounded function $f$ on $[a,b]$ is equivalent to the function $f$ being continuous almost everywhere on $[a,b]$. To create more sufficient conditions, just make up conditions that imply this one.